# Amazon EC2 VPC REST API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'm trying to perform a simple `GET` request to AWS EC2 (VPC), unfortunately i'm getting an error:

```
<Response>
<Errors>
<Error>
<Code>AuthFailure</Code>
<Message>
AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
</Message>
</Error>
</Errors>
<RequestID>9f0c9270-6234-44b4-b1a2-794edd150534</RequestID>
</Response>
```

This is the request that I'm making:

```
https://ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=MY_ACCESS_KEY&Action=DescribeImages&ImageId.1=MY_ID
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: The AWS Secret access key

Comment: Can you please provide an example ?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/CommonParameters.html#common-parameters-sigv2

Comment: It's not the Access Key Secret that is missing -- that never goes in a URL.  The *Signature*, however, is missing.

Comment: Yeah.. should I sign every time, or I can reuse the same signature?